# server always interpret some functions as lowercase

Tags: php

I have a function called myFunction() in function/function.php
in index.php, i called the function :

```
<div>
    <?php myFunction() ; ?>
</div>
```

but then i got error :

```
Call to undefined function myfunction() in index.php
```

Question : how come server interpret myFunction() as myfunction() ? Is there is any server configuration which automatically convert any function as lowercase?

Details :

1. I have make sure the name of the function declared in function.php is myFunction() {code} and stated in index as `<?php myFunction() ; ?>`
2. I did not put any string-related function to convert anything to lowercase above it
3. EDIT--Oh stupid me i forgot to check the import path carefully--I have properly imported function.php in index.php
4. I tested this in local server, and it works fine. This only happen when I tries to open it from the place where I hosted this code.
5. Also, i have /admin/test.php which also called myFunction(), but this one works fine, the function works properly even in hosting site.

myFunction() is of course, just an alias of the actual huge code, but I assure you that i did not import/implement/run any function that convert any string to lowercase above it

Comment: try if you will get true: `var_dump(function_exists('myFunction'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this works on your local server, but not on your host I would say this is a path problem.
You need to carefully check the path that you have used to import function.php. Make sure it is relative and not absolute.

Comment: Sorry, i just stupid not to check carefully the import path, Thank you very much. It works now, I forgot to add the "/"

Answer (score 1):

php function names [are](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) case-insensitive. Try reducing your code to a minimal example while making sure the problem still occurs. For example, the following code works fine for me and [codepad](http://codepad.org/lzV2Usse):

```
<?php
function myFunction() {echo "myFunction called.\n";}
myFunction();
```

Comment: Sorry, i just stupid not to check carefully the import path, Thank you very much. It works now, I forgot to add the "/"